# Plotly: How to prevent the outermost ring of a sunburst figure from being a lighter shade?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

Whenever I make a Plotly sunburst chart (I'm using Python) the outermost 'circle' or ring is is much lighter than the rest of the sunburst rings. How can I have the shade of this ring be the same as the rest of the chart?

As you can see, the segment labeled Bb5 is lighter than the rest.

[image]

I am using standard Plotly sunburst code. Simple example (will be lighter shade anyway):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parents=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    values=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4],
))
# Update layout for tight margin
# See https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
leaf=dict(opacity=1)
```

This sets the opacity of the leaves. With a specified colorscale it is defaulted to `1`, otherwise it is defaulted to `0.7`.

**Plot 1:** `leaf=dict(opacity=1)`

[image]

Now, compare this to:

**Plot 2:** `leaf=None`

Now, the opacity defaults to `0.7`

[image]

And take a look at what happens when you've specified a value for `colorscale`:

**Plot 3:** `colorscale='RdBu'`

If you leave out the leaf argument, the figure defaults to opacity = 1 for the leaves:

[image]

And lastly, you can have it both ways with `colorscale` *and* `leaf=dict(opacity=0.2)`. I'm just setting opacity very low here to make a clear point:

[image]

Here's the complete code for the case you were looking for:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parents=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    values=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4],
    leaf=dict(opacity=1),
    #marker=dict(colorscale='RdBu')
))

fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Question for @vestland : Do you know if there is a way to utilize `leaf` or another attribute to manipulate the opacity of different rings of a sunburst chart? I would be particularly interested in a way to set the center and outermost rings to full opacity but to leave the intermediate rings a lighter shade. In other words, is there a way to adjust branch opacity?

Comment: Apparently this leaf property not available under plotly.express.