# Is there a way to change the opacity of the leafs in a plotly.express.sunburst figure?

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram, plotly-express

I don't like the leaf categories having a different opacity and I couldn't find the setting to change it.

I found [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530929/plotly-how-to-prevent-the-outermost-ring-of-a-sunburst-figure-from-being-a-ligh) but I'm using plotly.express instead of plotly.graph_object. Is there a way to change it or do I have to try to change my px-figure into a graph_object?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba2Br.png)

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig =px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value',
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works regardless of whether you've used [Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) or [Plotly Graph Objects](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/) to build your figure:

```
fig.update_traces(leaf=dict(opacity = 1))
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig =px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value',
)

fig.update_traces(leaf=dict(opacity = 1))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As referenced in the related topic, transparency can be controlled with the corresponding graph object.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=data['character'],
    parents=data['parent'],
    values=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4],
    leaf=dict(opacity=1),
))

fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is a good reason why they are changing the transparency. I think the reason is to clarify the parent-child relationship. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer